# glassfish 3.1.1 WEB9031 exception for Time

Tags: rest, jersey, glassfish-3

I have an application that runs as a RESTWS on the glassfish 3.1.1 server. In case I get time during processing I am getting such an exception::

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [java.util.TimeZone], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

Searched the net but seems this exception comes for classloader problems. If anyone has found a solution for it please let me know.

Thanks Kavita